# UITextField with corner radius only on top or bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have a `UITextField` that is added to a view and I'm trying to change it's default appearance.

What I want is to change the corner radius, but only on top / bottom. I'm doing so by doing this:

```
UIBezierPath *usernameMaskPathWithRadiusTop = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:username.bounds
                                                                    byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight)
                                                                          cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(4.0, 4.0)];

UIBezierPath *passwordMaskPathWithRadiusBottom = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:password.bounds
                                                                       byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight)
                                                                             cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(4.0, 4.0)];

CAShapeLayer *usernameMaskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
usernameMaskLayer.frame = username.bounds;
usernameMaskLayer.path = usernameMaskPathWithRadiusTop.CGPath;

CAShapeLayer *passwordMaskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
passwordMaskLayer.frame = password.bounds;
passwordMaskLayer.path = passwordMaskPathWithRadiusBottom.CGPath;


[username setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
[username setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
usernameLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.0;
[usernameLayer setMask:usernameMaskLayer];

[password setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
[username setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
passwordLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.0;
[passwordLayer setMask:passwordMaskLayer];
```

Where `UITextField *username`, `UITextField *password` and the `CAShapeLayer *usernameLayer = username.layer` and `CAShapeLayer *passwordLayer = password.layer` are defined as described.

The issue is that after I perform that above, I get no fields at all, actually they are there but everything is transparent, text and background color. I'm not sure how to get that back or how to fix whatever I'm doing wrong.

How exactly can I do what I'm trying right ?

Comment: Try setting the `fillColor` of the `CAShapeLayer`.

Comment: I already tried that: `[passwordMaskLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];`, without any effect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like what I had to do is instead of setting a mask I had to add as sublayer:

```
[username.layer addSublayer:usernameMaskLayer];

// instead of the old

[usernameLayer setMask:usernameMaskLayer];
```

And then for setting a background I just had to `setFillColor` on the `usernameMaskLayer`.