# How to set square edges for UITextField in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xamarin

I'm trying to create a login page on my app with text fields that look like the email and password fields in this image:

[image]

I would like rounded tops and square bottoms. I know how to create fully rounded edges using quartz etc but I'm am unsure how to do half and half, I have found a few other posts on similar issues that suggest using something like `myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;` but obviously this does fully rounded not half.

Comment: Please refer this link for more info : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910361/uitextfield-with-corner-radius-only-on-top-or-bottom

Comment: you can use old dirty way with sectioned table view

Comment: `UIView` with two `UITextField` objects as subviews and the `UIView`'s layer has rounded corners, and the subviews are clipped. if someone wants to work out as asnwer, go for it, but the idea is that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this by setting textField's background image. It can be done in storyboad.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to make a `UIView` and place both fields in that view. Then , you can set the view to have rounded corners. It will achieve exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps more complicated than the suggestion by @George and @Holex, but you could do something like this:

TopTextField:

```
UIBezierPath *topMaskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:topTextField.bounds 
                                                  byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft| UIRectCornerTopRight                                                       
                                                        cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];
// Create the shape layer and set its path
CAShapeLayer *topMaskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
topMaskLayer.frame = topTextField.bounds;
topMaskLayer.path = topMaskPath.CGPath;
// Set the newly created shape layer as the mask for the image view's layer
topTextField.layer.mask = topMaskLayer;
```

BottomTextField:

```
UIBezierPath *bottomMaskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:topTextField.bounds 
                                                     byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft| UIRectCornerBottomRight                                                       
                                                           cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];
// Create the shape layer and set its path
CAShapeLayer *bottomMaskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
bottomMaskLayer.frame = bottomTextField.bounds;
bottomMaskLayer.path = bottomMaskPath.CGPath;
// Set the newly created shape layer as the mask for the image view's layer
bottomTextField.layer.mask = bottomMaskLayer;
```

Based on: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12491545/2611971)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use background image for textfield and buttons. Its only easiest way. I using images only for all my apps..